# React native link fails with no package found

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

I'm not sure what exactly is happening but I am unable to run react-native link without errors occuring

CLI Output:

```
react-native link --verbose
debug Available platforms: iOS, Android
debug Targeted platforms: iOS, Android
debug Getting project config for iOS...
debug Getting project config for Android...
error No package found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?
error Unexpected close tag
Line: 22
Column: 24
Char: >
debug Error: Unexpected close tag
Line: 22
Column: 24
Char: >
    at error (/Users/Dellybro/Desktop/App/AppReactNativeApp/node_modules/xmldoc/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:666:10)
    at strictFail (/Users/Dellybro/Desktop/App/AppReactNativeApp/node_modules/xmldoc/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:692:7)
    at closeTag (/Users/Dellybro/Desktop/App/AppReactNativeApp/node_modules/xmldoc/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:885:9)
    at SAXParser.write (/Users/Dellybro/Desktop/App/AppReactNativeApp/node_modules/xmldoc/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:1447:13)
    at new XmlDocument (/Users/Dellybro/Desktop/App/AppReactNativeApp/node_modules/xmldoc/lib/xmldoc.js:199:15)
    at readManifest (/Users/Dellybro/Desktop/App/AppReactNativeApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/android/readManifest.js:44:10)
    at Object.projectConfig (/Users/Dellybro/Desktop/App/AppReactNativeApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/android/index.js:66:46)
    at Object.keys.forEach.platform (/Users/Dellybro/Desktop/App/AppReactNativeApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/link/getProjectConfig.js:25:62)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at getProjectConfig (/Users/Dellybro/Desktop/App/AppReactNativeApp/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/link/getProjectConfig.js:22:35)
```

This randomly started happening after attempting to npm install react-native-firebase.

**What I've tried**

1. clear-caches
2. remove node_modules and npm install
3. Checking out my code back to a previous commit
4. Adding my package name to the manifest locaed in /android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
5. Removing the app from my computer and cloning it from github
6. Running react-native link on another project, which works, but i just can't run react-native link on this specific project.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer to my question was that in my android manifest xml file, there was an incorrect closing brace for one of my intent filters.

So for anyone that this happens to ensure that all of your Android files have correct syntax.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but I don't see anything wrong with my Manifest file. Could you mention the exact line you had the issue with as I could just not be noticing the syntax issue

Comment: I had a typo in AndroidManifest.xml file. Issue solved

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by closing some unclosed tag in `android/app/src/main/androidManifest.xml`. Try checking the file line by line.